# How do you render tooltip on disabled HTML Button

Tags: html, button, tooltip

I have a HTML button. I have tried to render a tooltip on it based on the "title" attribute of the button and it doesn't render. Mainly because it's disabled.

I then tried wrapping the button in a span and setting the "title" attribute of the span.

Hovering over the button that is wrapped in the span still has no effect. The tooltip will render on any other part of the span that is not part of the button tag. Like if I put some text in the span as well as the button, hovering over the text produces the tooltip, but if you hover over the button it will not render.

So: how can I display a tooltip for a disabled button?

Comment: I'm sorry, what's the question you're asking?

Comment: I would guess this can't be done with raw html and would require a javascript implementation.

Comment: There are some JavaScript solutions here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311574/how-to-enable-bootstrap-tooltip-on-disabled-button][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311574/how-to-enable-bootstrap-tooltip-on-disabled-button

Comment: See if your css has `pointer-events: none;` property or not, it could be a trap

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An ideal solution would be cross-browser compatible, and this suggestion isn't; I've tested it  only on Ubuntu 9.10, though with Chrome, Firefox, Epiphany and Opera and it seems to work reliably in those, which implies reliability in their Windows counterparts. Obviously IE is an entirely different kettle of fish.

That being said:

This idea's based on the following (x)HTML:

```html
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <button disabled title="this is disabled">disabled button</button>
    </fieldset>    
</form>
```

And uses the following CSS to achieve something close to your aim:

```css
button  {
    position: relative;
}

button:hover:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 75%;
    width: 100%;
    content: attr(title);
    background-color: #ffa;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
button:hover:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 75%;
  width: 100%;
  content: attr(title);
  background-color: #ffa;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #999;
}
```

```html
<form>

  <fieldset>

    <button disabled title="this is disabled">disabled button</button>

  </fieldset>

</form>
```

It's not ideal, but it was the best non-JavaScript idea I could come up with.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I hadn't mentioned specifically, but this needs to work in IE7+. Unfortunately it doesn't. In Firefox 3.5 it changes the preformatting of my buttons. Googling around and it seems to be a real problem for many. Thanks for your efforts

Comment: No worries, I'm thinking that JavaScript's probably going to be your best bet, then.

Comment: You cook fish in a tea kettle?

Comment: @Razor Storm: a kettle is just a piece of equipment in which water is contained while heated. In this instance '...different kettle of fish' is just an English figure of speech, though it refers to a fish-kettle (http://chefsblade.monster.com/training/articles/97)

Comment: Oh ok, makes sense now. I thought he was making a snide remark comparing programming for IE to cooking fish in an unconventional container.

Comment: Recently found this workaround after looking at links provided in Icedtoast's answer. I have not confirmed if it works though. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=274626#c16

Comment: @DavidThomas I have been looking for a way for the disabled button,It helped me and +1

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica um so, it shows **two** tooltips for me. The one from your CSS, and another one that's generated by the browser in default style (more like it's by the operating system, to be honest). What gives? https://i.imgur.com/5womuhg.png

Answer (score 74):

I got this working by applying the CSS `pointer-events: auto;` to the button, though this isn't supported on IE<11.

Comment: The trouble with this solution is that the "disabled" button can then be clicked and trigger the event which is supposed to be disabled.

Comment: @PaulMEdwards I did not have that problem with Chrome (75.0.3770.142)

Comment: Agreed with @PaulMEdwards

Comment: No, such button still can be triggered with keyboard (tab key + space key)

Comment: Neither Firefox nor Chrome in their latest versions seem to allow clicking or tab-focussing a disabled button with pointer-events auto, so this solution works great.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug in firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=274626

Comment: I provided a patch to Firefox for this issue, so hopefully it shouldn't be much longer.