# Add Bootstrap Tooltip when Bootstrap Switch is Disabled

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311574/how-to-enable-bootstrap-tooltip-on-disabled-button) using a Bootstrap Button I am looking to add a tooltip to appear when my Bootstrap Switch is disabled.

I have [this **JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/s537t380/6/) that disables the Switch when the map reaches a certain zoom as per the code below. I now want to add a tooltip that tells the user to zoom in when the Switch is disabled.

```
map.on('zoomend', function (e) {
    // Add/remove layers based on zoom level
    if (map.getZoom()>=5) {
        $("[name='my-checkbox2']").bootstrapSwitch('disabled',false);
    }
    else if (map.getZoom()<5) {
        $("[name='my-checkbox2']").bootstrapSwitch('disabled',true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you having a problem with your code? The example you've posted doesn't include anything related to a tooltip.

Comment: Sorry, should have said, that version of the JSFiddle is blank to add onto rather than my failed attempt.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) for tooltip. I'd think you could just manually show or hide the tooltip based on the logic you've already implemented.

Comment: okay then cheers, i'll look into that in a bit more detail, thought it might have been something that would be included an option of Bootstrap Switch but evidently not that i can tell.

Comment: @wahwahwah i looked at the bootstrap / bs switch docs and came to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/s537t380/7/) but not sure how to link to if the switch is disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is to no use to assign a tooltip to the checkbox itself, since it is hidden - instead show / hide a tooltip for the *outer* `.bootstrap-switch` element which the checkbox is wrapped into :

```
map.on('zoomend', function(e) {
    // Add/remove layers based on zoom level
    if (map.getZoom() >= 5) {
        $("[name='my-checkbox2']").bootstrapSwitch('disabled', false);

        $("[name='my-checkbox2']")
            .closest('.bootstrap-switch')
            .tooltip('destroy');

    } else if (map.getZoom() < 5) {
        $("[name='my-checkbox2']").bootstrapSwitch('disabled', true)

        $("[name='my-checkbox2']")
            .closest('.bootstrap-switch')
            .attr('title', 'Zoom more in')
            .tooltip();

    }
});
```

trigger `zoomend` immediately to update the tooltip status :

```
map.fireEvent('zoomend')
```

updated fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/ujzaakv3/3**

Comment: Thanks, the only issue with that is that when the switch is not disabled it still shows the tooltip when you hover over it?

Comment: @JoshuaDickerson, My bad :( Use `tooltip('destroy')` instead of `tooltip('hide')` of course -> **https://jsfiddle.net/ujzaakv3/1/**

Comment: Thanks, ah i tried 'disabled' and not 'destroy' works really well!

Comment: Is there a way of achieving this without attaching it to the `zoomend` function as it doesn't look great to the user that it pops up every time the map zooms in/out? Maybe just display when the user hovers over the disabled checkbox?

Comment: @JoshuaDickerson, I thought you want to have tooltip visible as default, just use `tooltip()` instead of `tooltip('show')` -> **https://jsfiddle.net/ujzaakv3/2/** by that the tooltip is only visible when the mouse hovering the bootstrap swtich.

Comment: Thanks, that's a simple fix. I guess this still relies on the user zooming in/ out at least once for the tooltip to show on hover as it needs the zoomend to complete first.

Comment: @JoshuaDickerson, Yes, obviously ...?? That was how your code was made. Just trigger `zoomend` by `map.fireEvent('zoomend')` if you want to avoid that - see updated answer.

Comment: Din't realise you could use the fireEvent like that, works a treat, really appreciate that addition!