# Add tooltip to a disabled bootstrap button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I've tried solutions found on other [similar threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43651179/bootstrap-tooltip-on-disabled-button-workaround), but can't get them working.

I've got a bootstrap button that, when in a disabled state, should have a tooltip letting the user know why it's disabled.

I understand that a button in disabled state has a CSS that prevents mouseover events from reaching the button element, and that there are workarounds for this.

What am I doing wrong in the below code?

```js
 // Grab button from DOM
 let resultsBtn = document.getElementById("get-results-btn");
 
 // if conditional is met, disable button
    $(resultsBtn).prop("disabled", true);
    
    // then, add tooltip 
       $(resultsBtn).attr("data-toggle", "tooltip");
       $(resultsBtn).attr("title", "you may only submit this form once");

       // add css rules to make tooltip work on disabled button
          $(resultsBtn).css("pointer-events", "none");
```

```css
/* ====================================== */
/* Button styling */
/* ====================================== */

#get-results-btn {
  // insert styling rules for color, size, etc. here, plus the following rules:
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  pointer-events: none; ////// Added this based on [S/O thread][1]
}

#get-results-btn  .btn[disabled] //// I pulled this line from [S/O thread][1], but I don't think the class applies to my code?
```

```html
<button id="get-results-btn" class="btn standard-btn-style">
  Get Results
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
 // Grab button from DOM
 let resultsBtn = "#wrapper";
 
 //// if conditional is met, disable button
 $("#get-results-btn").prop("disabled", true);
    
    // then, add tooltip 
       $(resultsBtn).attr("data-bs-toggle", "tooltip");
       $(resultsBtn).attr("title", "you may only submit this form once");
```

```css
#get-results-btn {
  display: inline-block;
}

#get-results-btn .btn[disabled] {
    pointer-events: none;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

<button id="get-results-btn" class="btn standard-btn-style">
  Get Results
</button>

</div>
 <!--CDNs-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Changes I made to your code:

- Added a wrapper div to the button, so the wrapper can show the tooltip
- You was added `pointer-events: none` to the wrong class. Corrected it.
- In javascript code, it should be `data-bs-toggle` not `data-toggle`.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#disabled-elements):

> Elements with the `disabled` attribute aren’t interactive, meaning
> users cannot focus, hover, or click them to trigger a tooltip (or
> popover). As a workaround, you’ll want to trigger the tooltip from a
> wrapper `<div>` or `<span>`, ideally made keyboard-focusable using
> `tabindex="0"`, and override the pointer-events on the disabled
> element.

**Example quoting from the documentation itself:**

```
<span class="d-inline-block" tabindex="0" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Disabled tooltip">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" style="pointer-events: none;" type="button" disabled>Disabled button</button>
</span>
```