# In Bootstrap, why doesn't my disabled button have a tooltip?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My JSFiddle is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/h2kf5ztq/

I've largely tried to reproduce balexand's answer from:

[How to enable bootstrap tooltip on disabled button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311574/how-to-enable-bootstrap-tooltip-on-disabled-button)

including, importantly, the CSS:

```
.tooltip-wrapper {
  display: inline-block; /* display: block works as well */
  margin: 50px; /* make some space so the tooltip is visible */
}

.tooltip-wrapper .btn[disabled] {
  /* don't let button block mouse events from reaching wrapper */
  pointer-events: none;
}

.tooltip-wrapper.disabled {
  /* OPTIONAL pointer-events setting above blocks cursor setting, so set it here */
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

But for some reason, my disabled button doesn't have a tooltip.

How do I enable the tooltip?

Comment: Did you look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311574/how-to-enable-bootstrap-tooltip-on-disabled-button

Comment: Yes, as can be seen in my question.

Comment: you are missing the jquery code to activate the tooltip:https://jsfiddle.net/ah3016vy/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to [activate your tooltip.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#tooltipoptions)

You can do this by adding `data-toggle="tooltip"` to your button wrapper, and then adding `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()` to your JS.

Also, there is a subsection showing the best way to [enable tooltips on disabled elements.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#disabled-elements)

Comment: Echoing this line in the documentation; `Tooltips are opt-in for performance reasons, so you must initialize them yourself.`

Answer (score 1):

First of all for initialize tooltip you need to call it by `javascript`

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

For calling `javascript` you need to have `data-toggle="tooltip"` in your HTML, There is only mistake you have.

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q18vefym/