# Vuetify date picker add tooltip in disabled days

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vuetify.js, tooltip

How to add tootlip in the disabled days when using the Vuetify's [date picker](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/)

I cannot seem to find it in documentation, is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can do this in Vuetify because there are no slots provided to customize the dates' display. I can think of one solution using pure JS. The strategy would be to-

***Find all disabled date elements and assign a `title` attribute (HTML tooltip) to it.***

**Important 1-** The `title` attribute will not work with the disabled elements, so, you need to use `pointer-events: auto` on that disabled element. (Reference from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32112741/11834856).)
**Important 2-** Above CSS will add a pointer cursor on the disabled button but it won't trigger any click event.

Here is a working demo. Try hovering on disabled dates and you should see a tooltip. Hope this helps.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    date: '2023-02-16',
  }),
  mounted() {
    let disabled_dates = document.querySelectorAll('.v-date-picker-table button');
    disabled_dates.forEach(date => {
      if(date.disabled) {
        date.title = "tooltip";
      }
    })
  },
  methods: {
    allowedDates: val => parseInt(val.split('-')[2], 10) % 2 === 0,
  },
})
```

```css
.v-btn--disabled {
  pointer-events: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row justify="center">
      <v-date-picker
        v-model="date"
        :allowed-dates="allowedDates"
        class="mt-4"
        min="2023-02-01"
        max="2023-02-28"
      ></v-date-picker>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```